# jQuery tablesorter in subHeader

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using jQuery tablesorter in my UI. I have a scenario where I have a table with 2 rows of headers. A main Header and a subheader. I want to add sorting to the subheader. How can i do that.

this is how my code looks like,

```
<table class="grid" id="gr1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
     <tr bgcolor="#FF0000"><th class="NOBORDER" colspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
     <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">A</th>
     <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">B</th>
     <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">C</th>
     <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">D</th>
     <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">E</th>
     <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">F</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <th>Group</th> 
     <th>A1</th>
     <th>A2</th>
     <th>A3</th>
     <th>B1</th>
     <th>B2</th>
     <th>B3</th>
     <th>C1</th>
     <th>C2</th>
     <th>C3</th>
     <th>D1</th>
     <th>D2</th>
     <th>D3</th>
     <th>E1</th>
     <th>E2</th>
     <th>E3</th>
     <th>F1</th>
     <th>F2</th>
     <th>F3</th>
    </tr>
```

From this table I would want to sort the group column in the 2nd row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues with the table ([working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/409/)):

1. tablesorter requires a table with a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` before it will even initialize. There isn't a full table displayed in the sample, so I can only assume the `<tbody>` might also be missing.

   ```
   <table class="grid tablesorter" id="gr1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
       <thead>
           <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
               <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
               <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">A</th>
               ...
               <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">F</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <th>Group</th>
               <th>A1</th>
               <th>A2</th>
               <th>A3</th>
               <th>B1</th>
               ...
               <th>F3</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>...</tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```
2. The original version of [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) requires the `"tablesorter"` class name to be added to the table before any styling will be applied.
3. The original version also doesn't seem to work well with multiple functional rows in the `<thead>`. So disable sorting in the top row to get sorting to work properly in the third column (well fourth column, but third in each group). Try this initialization code:

   ```
   $('table').tablesorter({
       headers : {
           0 : { sorter: false },
           1 : { sorter: false },
           2 : { sorter: false },
           3 : { sorter: false },
           4 : { sorter: false },
           5 : { sorter: false },
           6 : { sorter: false }   
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a table inside a table with the tablesorter applied to the inner table. The inner table will have the second row of headers while the outer table will have the first. You will have to work on the css/widths though which would merge the outer table seamlessly with the inner table.
So your code would look like this:

```
<table class="outerTableLook" id="OuterTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr bgcolor="#FF0000"><th class="NOBORDER" colspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
 <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">A</th>
 <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">B</th>
 <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">C</th>
 <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">D</th>
 <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">E</th>
 <th class="NOBORDER" colspan="3">F</th>
 </tr>
<tr>
<table class="grid" id="gr1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
 <tr>
 <th>Group</th> 
 <th>A1</th>
 <th>A2</th>
 .......
</tr>  
....
</table><!--inner table -->
</tr>
</table><!-- outer table -->
```